# 400 Bad request While executing API post script in Loadrunner

Tags: api, post, performance-testing, loadrunner, http-status-code-400

i am trying to prepare script for API post request to login as follows

```
web_rest("POST: http://remote-data-dashboard-app.apps.eu01.cf.cano...",
    "URL=http://remote-data-dashboard-app.apps.eu01.cf.canopy-cloud.com/login",
    "Method=POST",
    "EncType=raw",
    "Snapshot=t700233.inf",
    "Body={\n"
    ""username":"XXXX",\n"
    ""password":"XXXXX"\n"
    "}",
    HEADERS,
    "Name=Accept", "Value=application/json", ENDHEADER,
    "Name=Accept-Charset", "Value=UTF-8", ENDHEADER,
    "Name=Content-Type", "Value=application/json", ENDHEADER,
    LAST);
```

But it throws error saying 400 bad request(syntactical errors).But i have checked many times but it looks fine with the URL and parameters as i have used same for Jmeter and its working fine their.
Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to escape the "

```
web_rest("POST: http://remote-data-dashboard-app.apps.eu01.cf.cano...",
    "URL=http://remote-data-dashboard-app.apps.eu01.cf.canopy-
     cloud.com/login",
    "Method=POST",
    "EncType=raw",
    "Snapshot=t700233.inf",
    "Body={\n"
    "\"username\":\"XXXX\",\n"
    "\"password\":\"XXXXX\"\n"
    "}",
    HEADERS,
    "Name=Accept", "Value=application/json", ENDHEADER,
    "Name=Accept-Charset", "Value=UTF-8", ENDHEADER,
    "Name=Content-Type", "Value=application/json", ENDHEADER,
    LAST);
```